# C++ lambda expression in std::find_if?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, lambda

I've got a std::map that contains a class and that class has an id. I have an id that I'm trying to find in the set

```
typedef std::set<LWItem> ItemSet;
ItemSet selectedItems;
LWItemID i = someID;

ItemSet::iterator isi;
isi = std::find_if(selectedItems.begin(), selectedItems.end(), [&a](LWItemID i)->bool { return a->GetID()==i; }
```

I get an error saying that the lambda capture variable is not found, but I have no idea what I'm supposed to do to get it to capture the container contents as it iterates through.
Also, I know that I cant do this with a loop, but I'm trying to learn lambda functions.

Comment: Where did you declare `a`? What are you searching in? `map` or `set`?

Comment: `selectedItems` is a container of `LWItem`s, so the lambda can't take an `LWItemID` as an argument. It has to take an `LWItem` (possible a `const &`)

Comment: Apologies if it seems like a stupid question. My main problem seemed to be that I wasn't sure how to capture the local `LWItem` variable, `i`, and the element being iterated via `std::find_if`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You've got your capture and argument reversed.  The bit inside the `[]` is the capture; the bit inside `()` is the argument list.  Here you want to capture the local variable `i` and take `a` as an argument:

```
[i](LWItem a)->bool { return a->GetID()==i; }
```

This is effectively a shorthand for creating a functor class with local variable `i`:

```
struct {
   LWItemID i;
   auto operator()(LWItem a) -> bool { return a->GetID()==i; } 
} lambda = {i};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This'll teach me to try and code when I'm super tired (though I never seem to learn).

Answer (score 14):

From what i understand you code should look like this :

```
auto foundItem = std::find_if(selectedItems.begin(), selectedItems.end(), 
[&i](LWItem const& item) 
{ 
return item->GetID() == i; 
});
```

This will capture the LWItem that have an ID equal to i, with i being a previosuly declared ID.